# Custom background or icon for UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios7

Is it possible to customize background color, icon or add image for `UILocalNotification`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only customisation you can make is using the `alertLaunchImage` property. You can also add a badge to the icon, but there's no way to dynamically customise the app icon.